# usually and present continuous

Tags: continuous

> It is not  the thousand beers you had
>
> there is something  in your eye
>
> which **usually** you **are trying**  to hide
>
> blaming the girls dancing around

why is "usually" following by gerund? it is a bit opposite continuous and usually .
In this case, does it mean that in fact the person can't  manage to hide what he woud like to and this state is an habit :that is why usually is used.

Comment: Where does that sentence come from?

Answer (score 1):

It's not followed by a gerund, which would be a noun, it's followed by the present participle of the [present continuous](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-continuous/): you **are trying**.

It's appropriate because *usually* means "normally" or "at most times", and at most times (that we are talking about) you are in the middle of the action of *trying to hide* etc.  The author could have used the simple present, "usually you *try* to hide",

Comment: yes of course it is present continuous why did I write gerund